# Использование "при этом" внутри деепричастного оборота бессмысленно

Tags: значение-слов, семантика, деепричастный-оборот, смысл

По-моему деепричастный оборот, как конструкция, сам по себе несёт смысл, передаваемый словами "при этом". Интересны размышления насчёт истинности утверждения в заголовке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Утверждение в заголовке в общем случае ложно.

Простой пример:
*Он глубоко задумался, рассматривая чёрную точку на потолке*;
*Он глубоко задумался, рассматривая при этом чёрную точку на потолке*.

Если мы хотим подчеркнуть, что действия просто происходят одновременно и не связаны между собой причинно-следственной связью, уместно будет употребить **при этом**. В первом случае нельзя уверенно утверждать, что причиной задумчивости стала чёрная точка (впрочем, многие подумают, что именно так и было), но в контексте это может быть однозначно определено. Понятно, что в таком случае использовать **при этом** уже нельзя.

Можно подобрать и другие примеры, демонстрирующие более тонкие стилистические и семантические особенности употребления наречного выражения **при этом** в деепричастных оборотах.

Comment: Спасибо, согласен. Интересны другие примеры, в которых **при этом** употребляется с иной целью.

Comment: @mesher.x Довольно сложно объяснять очевидные вещи. Попытайтесь сами подобрать такие примеры, это несложно. Можно ли сказать: "он заключил сделку, получив задаток"? А так: "он напился, получив задаток"? А теперь попытайтесь в эти предложения добавить **при этом**. Почувствуйте разницу. Чем отличается этот пример от данного в ответе?